# plot of categorical variables with R

Tags: r, plot

I'm a newcomer both to R and statistics in general.
I'm trying to plot the relationship of two categorical variables which are vectors of length 147.
The tables for each are:

```
    AgeGroup
26-49   50-64   65 and over  Under 26
101     16      5            25
```

and

```
    Role
A/C     C/H                     Dietician
6       8                       2
Doctor  Healthcare Assistant    Lab
56      7                       2
Nurse   Pharmacist              Phlebotomist
54      5                       1
Radiographer                    Therapist
1                               5
```

After reading an answer to a question here from 2012 I expected to get a spineplot by using this command:

```
    plot(mydata$Role,mydata$AgeGroup,xlab="Role",ylab="Age Group")
```

but it returns:

```
    Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I'm guessing that Warning message 1 is telling me that xycoords() is attempting to
coerce the categorial elements into numeric data and when it fails to do so
is returning NAs, which gives plot() nothing to work with.
In short, what am I failing to understand and how do I fix it?

Comment: There is a plot.table method so why not try:`with( mydata, plot( table(Role, AgeGroup), xlab="Role",ylab="Age Group")`

Comment: Thanks, that looks great! Now I can spend some time figuring out how it works :-)

Comment: `with` creates a local environment where the column names are interpreted as objects, and within that env, a table object is passed to `plot`. The `plot` function is generic (try typing `methods(plot)` ) so it looks up the proper method for the 'table'-classed object and does its work. To see the code for `plot.table` which is not exported, you need to use `getAnywhere(plot.table)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess I might as well put my comments in  an answer:

There is a plot.table method so why not try:with( mydata, plot( table(Role, AgeGroup), xlab="Role",ylab="Age Group") –  BondedDust 3 hours ago

`with` creates a local environment where the column names are interpreted as objects, and within that environment, a 'table'-object is passed to `plot`. The `plot` function is generic (try typing `methods(plot)` ) so it looks up the proper method for the 'table'-classed object and does its work. To see the code for `plot.table` which is not exported, you need to use `getAnywhere(plot.table)`

Comment: Making sense of the documentation and error messages is going to take me a LONG time, the help you provide is invaluable, thanks very much.